# apex:outputText doesn't display. why?

Tags: visualforce

I have this code in a vf page

```
<apex:outputText value="{!progName}" escape="false"> </apex:outputText>
```

and in the controller,

```
String progName { get; set; }
progName = 'test';
```

I do not get an error but the progName doesn't display. Why?

What I really want is to put a full message in the outputtext like

```
<apex:outputText value="Please choose something for {!progName}" escape="false"> </apex:outputText>`
```

Comment: Is that **public** String progName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your progName is not being set correctly.

Either set it in your constructor like :

```
public YouClassConstructor (){
        ...
        progName  = 'test';
        ....
    }
```

or in the method where the action call is being set

Answer (score 4):

Your controller code needs to be revised to

```
Public String progName { get; set; }
```

Then, in whatever method progName is set, it will then be set in the page

```
progName = 'test';
```

Comment: I had it as public, I just didn't paste it in the code sample above. Do I need to make a special method to set the value? It somehow doesn't show on the vf page.

Comment: @ApexN-u-b try setting progName in the constructor as a test, it seems like it's not being set correctly.

Comment: @Raym0nd: It worked. Many thanks. If you make it an answer I will mark it as done

Answer (score 0):

You should be missing assignment of progName in constructor.
Please check what are you missing by below code.

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="OutputTextPageController">
 <apex:outputText value="Please choose something for {!progName}" escape="false"> </apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class OutputTextPageController {

    public String progName { get; set; }

    public OutputTextPageController (){
        progName  = 'Test';
    }
}
```

Output

[image]